# Unresponsive Keyboard and Trackpad in Macbook Pro High Sierra 10.13.5

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, trackpad

I have a strange issue with this macbook. The built in keyboard and trackpad just all of a sudden died (no light in caps lock for example). Nothing works. But if I plug in a usb mouse and external keyboard they both work fine. Its not a hardware issue because If I use a linux live usb key and boot into it at start up the keyboard and trackpad work fine.

I was wondering if anyone else has had a similar issue. I've seen issues like this, but those are all from a few years ago at least.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what model MacBook you have, but Apple just recently issued a "Keyboard Service Program for MacBook and MacBook Pro." Check out this link (https://www.apple.com/support/keyboard-service-program-for-macbook-and-macbook-pro) to see if your model is eligible. Hope this helps :)